# SAS Proc Summary with class variables that have missing values

Tags: sas, procedure

I'm having an issue with how proc summary behaves when variables in the class statement have missing values. In the example below, **test_out** will give all possible combinations of types. **test_missing_out** does not and does not take into account *var3* for the sum where *var2* was missing, despite the fact *var1* was not missing:

```
data test;
    infile datalines dsd delimiter=' ';
    input var1 var2 $ var3;
    datalines;
1 data 200
2 data2 103
;
run;

proc summary
    data=test;
    class var1 var2;
    var var3;
    output out=test_out sum=sum;
run;


data test_missing;
    infile datalines dsd delimiter=' ';
    input var1 var2 $ var3;
    datalines;
1 data 200
2  103
;
run;

proc summary
    data=test_missing;
    class var1 var2;
    var var3;
    output out=test_missing_out sum=sum; 
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proc summary has a lot in common with proc means concerning syntax.
You can simply add the keyword MISSING to the proc summary statement if you want it to consider missing values as a grouping level:

```
proc summary
data=test_missing
MISSING;
class var1 var2;
var var3;
output out=test_missing_out sum=sum; 
run;
```

Comment: PROC SUMMARY is identical to PROC MEANS except in the default printed output/dataset output options.

Comment: To add to this, the SAS docs for proc means contain the MISSING option http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm